# Sample scala higher-order function explaination

Tags: scala

```
object Demo {
     def main(args: Array[String]) {
          println( apply( layout, 10) )
     }

     def apply(f: Int => String, v: Int) = f(v)

     def layout[A](x: A) = "[" + x.toString() + "]"
}
```

I am new to Scala and a bit confused about the code above.

From my understanding, `apply` takes another function and an integer as inputs. 
And it passes the integer `v` to function `f` as its input parameter.
What does `layout[A]` mean here ?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax

```
def layout[A](x:A)
```

declares a new generic function. In this case, the function `layout` is generic in its one and only parameter so you could call `layout` on ANY value and that would be legal Scala.

In Java this would be written as a method to some class, but the syntax is similar:

```
String layout<A>(A x)
```

[Twitter's Scala school has a good explanation](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html) to how types are used in Scala.

Answer (score 1):

It's called a type parameter.

If you write `def f(x: Int) = ....`, the compiler now knows that all the following references to `x` will involve some integer value.

If you write `def f(x: A) = ....`, the compiler will complain, "A? What's A? I don't know what A is!"

If you write `def f[A](x: A) = ....`, the compiler knows that the real type of `x` will be provided, or can be inferred from the context, when `f` is called.

Comment: I got it now . Thanks !